# How to check for both duplicate letters and non–alphabetic characters?

Tags: c

My program should keep prompting the user to enter the correct format of string if there are duplicates of letters or the string contains non-alphabetic characters.

However, it does not work correctly. It seems that it cannot find out whether characters are alphabetic or not, while works fine to distinguish duplicate letters and keep prompting the user to enter string one more time.

Also, I've tried to do it without `isalpha()` function. Instead of that, I checked for condition of uppercase character belonging into the range between `'A'` and `'Z'`. Even in that case the program did not work right.

Here is the function and test that I've tried:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int check(char key[]) {
   int flag = 1;
   int counts[strlen(key)];

   int i, j;

   for (i = 0; i < strlen(key); i++) {
       counts[i] = 0;
   }

   for (i = 0; i < strlen(key); i++) {
       for (j = 0; j < strlen(key); j++) {
           if (toupper(key[i]) == toupper(key[j])) {
               counts[i]++;
           }
       }
   }

   for (i = 0; i < strlen(key); i++) {
       if (counts[i] > 1 || isalpha(key[i]) == 0) {
           /* if I remove 
              isalpha related condition it works fine 
              to find only duplicate letters
              and keep asking user to input 
              another string */
           flag = 0;
       }
   }
   return flag;
}

int main() {
   int size = 20;
   char str[size];

   printf("Enter a string w/o duplicate letters and non-alphabetic characters: ");
   fgets(str, size, stdin);

   //test 1. str = "hello" -> prompt to enter str again since there 2 'l's (this part works well but only to find duplicate letters)
   //test 2. str = "helo12" -> prompt to enter str again since there are non-alphabetic characters
   //test 3. str = "naruto" -> program keeps working further
   while (check(str) != 1) {
       printf("Illegal word! \nEnter again: ");
       fgets(str, size, stdin);
   }
}
```

Comment: Edit to include a sample input series, The response series you are seeing, and the expected series you wnat to see.  (i.e. _series_ in this context means character series.)

Comment: A line read in with `fgets` retains the non-alphabetic new-line character, so what you see might be `"ambidextrous\n"`. Remove it before you process the string. ([Here's how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28462221/2979617).)

Comment: Your check function is doing too much.  Once you know you have a failure, stop checking. eg `int check(char *key){ int counts[256] = {0}; for( ; *key && *key != '\n'; key++) { if(counts[toupper(*key)]++ == 1 || ! isalpha(*key)) { return 1; } } return 0; }`

Comment: the function: `strlen()` returns a value with type `size_t`, NOT `int`.  Suggest your loop counters: `i` and `j` be declared as `size_t`, not `int`

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results.

Comment: @ryyker,  Not an `int` variable,  rather a `size_t` variable

Comment: OT:  in general, it is best to limit the scope of variables as much as reasonable.  Therefore, the `for()` statements (which currently are: `for (i = 0; i < strlen(key); i++) {`  would be much better written as: `for ( size_t i = 0; i < strlen(key); i++) {`

Comment: OT regarding: `int size = 20;`  This would be much better placed just after the `#include` statements and written as: `#define SIZE 20`  Then use: `SIZE` everywhere that `size` is currently being used.

Comment: regarding: `for (i = 0; i < strlen(key); i++) {
       for (j = 0; j < strlen(key); j++) {
           if (toupper(key[i]) == toupper(key[j])) {
               counts[i]++;
           }
       }
   }`  This will increment `counts` once for every time the indexes `i` and `j` are the same (besides every time there is a duplicate letter.  Not what you want to do.

Comment: regarding: `fgets(str, size, stdin);`  There are many things a user could do to cause this to fail, including entering a EOF   Therefore, always check the returned value (not the contents of `str`) to assure the user has not messed up the input operation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `check()` function should work as expected but you do not strip the trailing newline left in `str` by `fgets()`, causing the `check()` to fail.

Note also that `isalpha()` and `toupper()` are undefined for negative values, which is the case of non-ASCII bytes on platforms where `char` is signed by default. Use `isalpha((unsigned char)key[i])` and `toupper((unsigned char)key[i])` to avoid this problem.

Here is a simpler method:

```c
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int check(const char *key) {
    while (*key) {
        unsigned char c = *key++;
        if (!isalpha(c))
            return 0;
        if (strchr(key, c) || strchr(key, tolower(c)) || strchr(key, toupper(c)))
            return 0;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main() {
   char str[20];

   printf("Enter a string without duplicate letters or non-alphabetic characters: ");
   if (!fgets(str, sizeof str, stdin))
       return 1;
   str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0'; // strip the trailing newline if any

   // test 1. str = "hello"  -> prompt to enter str again since there are 2 'l's
   // test 2. str = "helo12" -> prompt to enter str again since there are non-alphabetic characters
   // test 3. str = "naruto" -> program keeps working further
   while (check(str) != 1) {
       printf("Illegal word!\nEnter again: ");
       if (fgets(str, sizeof size, stdin) == NULL)
           return 1;
       str[strcspn(str, "\n")] = '\0'; // strip the trailing newline if any
   }
   printf("String is valid: %s\n", str);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Another simple approach rather than multiple comparisons is to check against an accepted character set with `strspn` and then check for duplicates. In your case you could define the accepted characters as the alpha characters and then use a simple frequency array to check for duplicates, e.g.

```
#define ACCEPT "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

int check (char *s)
{
    int freq['Z'-'A'+1] = {0};

    if (s[strspn(s, ACCEPT)])           /* validate all alpha-char */
        return 0;

    for (int i = 0; s[i]; i++)          /* check for dups */
        if (++freq[toupper(s[i]) -'A'] > 1)
            return 0;

    return 1;
}
```

(**note:** the characters are converted to upper-case for the frequency comparison)

In the first case if the "length" of the string is not equal to the number of acceptable characters in the string, you have an unwanted character. If all characters are acceptable, `strspn` returns the length leaving `s[length]` as the nul-character (or just `0`) The next loop just loops over each character and if any appear more than once, the string fails the test.

A short example incorporating the test could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXC 256
#define ACCEPT "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

int check (char *s)
{
    int freq['Z'-'A'+1] = {0};

    if (s[strspn(s, ACCEPT)])           /* validate all alpha-char */
        return 0;

    for (int i = 0; s[i]; i++)          /* check for dups */
        if (++freq[toupper(s[i]) -'A'] > 1)
            return 0;

    return 1;
}

int main (void) {

    char str[MAXC];

    for (;;) {  /* loop continually until valid input received */
        fputs ("enter string, alpha-only w/o duplicates: ", stdout);
        if (!fgets (str, MAXC, stdin)) {        /* validate read */
            puts ("(user canceled input)");     /* handle EOF */
            return 1;
        }
        str[strcspn (str, "\n")] = 0;           /* remove '\n' */
        if (check (str))                        /* if good str, break */
            break;
        fputs ("error: invalid entry\n\n", stderr);
    }

    printf ("\ngood str: %s\n", str);           /* output result */
}
```

Another way to *skin-the-cat* in C.

Answer (score 0):

you need to stop in strlen(key)**-1**, and **return** flag=0 as soon as you find a number

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int check(char key[]) {
   int flag = 1;
   int counts[strlen(key)];

   int i, j;

   for (i = 0; i < strlen(key); i++) {
       counts[i] = 0;
   }

   for (i = 0; i < strlen(key); i++) {
       for (j = 0; j < strlen(key); j++) {
           if (toupper(key[i]) == toupper(key[j])) {
               counts[i]++;
           }
       }
   }

   for (i = 0; i < strlen(key)-1; i++) {
       if (counts[i] > 1 || isalpha(key[i])==0 ) {
           /* if I remove
              isalpha related condition it works fine
              to find only duplicate letters
              and keep asking user to input
              another string */
           return flag = 0;
       }
   }
   return flag;
}

int main() {
   int size = 20;
   char str[size];

   printf("Enter a string w/o duplicate letters and non-alphabetic characters: ");
   fgets(str, size, stdin);

   //test 1. str = "hello" -> prompt to enter str again since there 2 'l's (this part works well but only to find duplicate letters)
   //test 2. str = "helo12" -> prompt to enter str again since there are non-alphabetic characters
   //test 3. str = "naruto" -> program keeps working further
   while (check(str) != 1) {
       printf("Illegal word! \nEnter again: ");
       fgets(str, size, stdin);
   }
}
```

Comment: Stopping at `strlen(str)-1` will prevent the detection of a non-alpha character at the end of the string.

Comment: no it is done to stop it from checking \n and giving wrong output. try it it works perfectly

Comment: Not stripping the newline **is** the error in the posted code. Bending the semantics of the `check()` function is not the proper way to fix the problem. As a matter of fact, try entering `toto!`Ctrl-D and you will see that `toto!` will be accepted with the trailing `!` because it does not have a trailing newline. Furthermore, you will see that the program goes into an infinite loop because end-of-file is not properly tested either.

Comment: I tried toto! and it was not accepted. Also i could not find information about ! not having a newline after it in google.

Comment: you did not signal the end of file after the `!`. If the last line input has no newline, the last character is not tested, hence `toto!` would be accepted if followed immediately by the end of file.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working well. You just have to remove trailing newline character from `fgets()` input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
 int check(char key[]) {
  int flag = 1;
  int counts[strlen(key)];

    int i, j;

   for (i = 0; i < strlen(key); i++) {
     counts[i] = 0;
    }

   for (i = 0; i < strlen(key); i++) {
     for (j = 0; j < strlen(key); j++) {
        if (toupper(key[i]) == toupper(key[j])) {
           counts[i]++;
       }
   }
 }

  for (i = 0; i < strlen(key); i++) {
      if (counts[i] > 1 || isalpha(key[i]) == 0) {
        /* if I remove 
          isalpha related condition it works fine 
          to find only duplicate letters
          and keep asking user to input 
          another string */
       flag = 0;
   }
 }
  return flag;
 }


 int main() {
    int size = 20;
    char str[size];

    printf("Enter a string w/o duplicate letters and non-alphabetic characters: ");
    fgets(str, size, stdin);
   str[strcspn(str, "\r\n")] = 0;

         //test 1. str = "hello" -> prompt to enter str again since there 2 'l's (this part works well but only to find duplicate letters)
         //test 2. str = "helo12" -> prompt to enter str again since there are non-alphabetic characters
       //test 3. str = "naruto" -> program keeps working further
      while (check(str) != 1) {
         printf("Illegal word! \nEnter again: ");
         fgets(str, size, stdin);
          str[strcspn(str, "\r\n")] = 0;
        }
       }
```

Comment: both are the same, I used to write this way.